# Input field "date" has unknown spacing in iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, date, input, spacing

Since it's a private project which should work on iPads only, I don't care that much about design in other browsers than Safari.

I'm currently trying to create an input field for dates. It works so far, but I absolutely have no clue where the spacing (marked with red line) comes from. Other input fields like texts above and below, doesnt have this spacing. I also tried to add/remove padding and margin, but it doesn't seem to work and I just want to use type="date" because of the datepicker in iOS Safari.

Do you have an idea?

```
<div class="any-class-i-want">
    <span class="text-very-small">A random text on the left side</span>
    <input type="date" class="text-right" value="">
</div>
```

```
input {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 @row-space / 2;
    background-color: #ABC;
    //-moz-appearance: textfield;

    &::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
    &::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        margin-right: 50px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    &:focus {
        outline: none !important;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much, I really appreciate your support!

[image: Where does the spacing (red line behind dates) comes from?]